# Python Join the matched line with just before matched

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Experts, Just trying to match a string in a log file and add or join the line with just a line before match, saying that.. join the matched line with one line just before it.

I'm trying below code getting hints from SO, However it working printing matched line with the Just line before. However i want to join these two `matched` `+`  `before line` .

```
#!/bin/python3
# Print adding matched line with just one line before
with open('smbd.log.old') as input:
    lines = tuple(input)  
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if 'failed' in line or 'Timed' in line:
        print(*lines[max(i-1, 0):i], line, sep='') # need help to understand this section
```

**Output from the above code:**

```
[2020/02/19 04:01:15.729527,  0] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:998(smbldap_connect_system)
  failed to bind to server ldap://myldap1.example.com ldap://myldap2.example.com with dn="cn=sambaAdmin,ou=users,o=services" Error: Can't contact LDAP server

[2020/02/19 04:01:15.729696,  1] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:1206(get_cached_ldap_connect)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 1 try!

[2020/02/19 04:01:15.729717,  2] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:287(smbldap_search_domain_info)
  smbldap_search_domain_info: Problem during LDAPsearch: Timed out
```

**Sample log file data:**

```
[2020/02/18 08:25:21.228421,  0] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:998(smbldap_connect_system)
  failed to bind to server ldap://myldap1.example.com ldap://myldap2.example.com with dn="cn=sambaAdmin,ou=users,o=services" Error: Can't contact LDAP server
        (unknown)
[2020/02/18 08:25:21.229198,  1] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:1206(get_cached_ldap_connect)
  Connection to LDAP server failed for the 1 try!
[2020/02/18 08:25:21.229221,  2] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:287(smbldap_search_domain_info)
  smbldap_search_domain_info: Problem during LDAPsearch: Timed out
[2020/02/18 08:25:21.229229,  2] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:288(smbldap_search_domain_info)
  smbldap_search_domain_info: Query was: ou=TDL,o=HPP, (&(objectClass=sambaDomain)(sambaDomainName=INV1506))
[2020/02/18 08:25:21.229244,  0] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap.c:6534(pdb_ldapsam_init_common)
  pdb_init_ldapsam: WARNING: Could not get domain info, nor add one to the domain. We cannot work reliably without it.
[2020/02/18 08:25:21.229256,  0] ../source3/passdb/pdb_interface.c:179(make_pdb_method_name)
  pdb backend ldapsam:"ldap://myldap1.example.com ldap://myldap2.example.com" did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO)
[2020/02/19 03:54:46.677689,  1] ../lib/param/loadparm.c:1729(lpcfg_do_global_parameter)
  WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
```

**Desired:**

```
[2020/02/19 04:01:15.729527,  0] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:998(smbldap_connect_system) failed to bind to server ldap://myldap1.example.com ldap://myldap2.example.com with dn="cn=sambaAdmin,ou=users,o=services" Error: Can't contact LDAP server

[2020/02/19 04:01:15.729696,  1] ../source3/lib/smbldap.c:1206(get_cached_ldap_connect) Connection to LDAP server failed for the 1 try!

[2020/02/19 04:01:15.729717,  2] ../source3/passdb/pdb_ldap_util.c:287(smbldap_search_domain_info) smbldap_search_domain_info: Problem during LDAPsearch: Timed out
```

Comment: Hint: remember the previous line along with the current line.

Comment: I understand your question is about python, but is there any reason you’re not using grep, a tool specifically made for this sort of situation? “grep -B1 -E ‘(failed|Timed)’ smbd.log.old” for example.

Comment: @smassey, indeed it could be done with grep,awk,sed but i'm just trying to learn the python and python way of doing it :-) , though `grep -B1 -E '(failed|Timed)' smbd.log.old` will not join the two lines into one though it will pront both matched and one line before.

Comment: @9000, thanks for  the hint , i'm trying to understand and applying whatever i know, will try and let you know :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick sketch:

```py
prev_line = "<no previous line>"
with open(...) as input_file:
  for line_no, line in enumerate(input_file, start=1):
    # Reading one line at a time suffices.
    if 'failed' in line or 'Timed' in line:
      print(line_no - 1, prev_line)
      print(line_no, line)
    prev_line = line  # Remember for next time.
```

Comment: it does not work, it agian gives both the matched and before line into two diffrent line while i need them concatenated.

Comment: Then just put them into _one_ `print` invocation.

Comment: I have tried, `print(prev_line.rstrip('\n'),line)` and it works.... i just removed the `line_no` which is line denominator.